# Capturing first 4 characters of a Windows command line output to variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, command-line

I'm trying to capture the first 4 characters of output from the following Windows command.

```
nltest /server:%COMPUTERNAME% /dsgetsite
```

What is normally returned would be:

```
SITEAdSiteName
This command completed successfully.
```

I've tried using the `for /F` command but can't seem to figure out how to strip everything else except the first 4 characters of what is returned.

I'm thinking using the `for /F` may not be the best way to accomplish this.

Are there other suggestions on how I many accomplish this?

I think my challenge is defining (or not) the delimiter to being any character, I've tried the *, but didn't seem to do it for me.

When I use this:

```
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=*" %A in ('nltest /server:%COMPUTERNAME% /dsgetsite') DO echo %A
```

I get both output lines, sort of stumped here.

Comment: Do you insist on using a command directly from the prompt, or are you looking for a batch file? Do you want just the first 4 characters of the first line, the last line, or every line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store the first line of the output of `nltest /server:%COMPUTERNAME% /DSGETSITE` in variable `LINE`, use the following command line (use `%%F` instead of `%F` to use this in a batch file):

```cmd
set "LINE=" & for /F %F in ('nltest /server:%COMPUTERNAME% /DSGETSITE') do if not defined LINE set "LINE=%F"
```

To return the first four characters, use [sub-string expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html):

```cmd
set "LINE=%LINE:~,4%"
echo %LINE%
```